# Can I train a model directly at onnx?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, c++

I'm trying to make an unreal engine game and I recently discovered that I can use onnx as my training framework, so I can load models at c++. I pretend to make reinforcement learning agents for my npcs, but the problem is that I only discovered how to implement a model that's already trained. Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to train the model directly from onnx at c++; and if I can make a training pipeline, so I can train my agents in real time too.